# Looking for an AR outdoor navigation development framework

Tags: ios, api, gis, navigation, augmented-reality

I am looking for recommendations for an API or SDK that I can use to create an augmented reality (AR) outdoor navigation app. I would like to be able to input spatial data such as mountain peaks or lakes. The app should be able to navigate to these points of interest in an augmented reality environment.

Here is an [example](https://www.outdooractive.com/en/knowledgepage/identify-peaks-lakes-and-places-with-skyline-augmented-reality/44736566/) of an an app that does some of what I am after. Essentially, I want to know if there is a set of AR development tools that I can use to create this type of app. I would prefer to develop this app in iOS.